# wrong number of arguments (5 for 4) Rails 4.1.14.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have upgraded our rails to 4.1.14.1 and its dependencies however when I try to render a file,

```
def show
  path = Rails.root.join('spec','javascripts','fixtures', "#{params[:id]}.html")
  render file: path, layout: nil
end
```

the render action reports a wrong number of arguments (5 for 4) error. What could be why all of the sudden, this version of rails does not want to find the file? I know that this works with our prior version of Rails, 4.1.11, and the Rails docs are saying that my render is legal.

Edit: When I try rails 4.1.14, that works. I wonder why there is a difference?

Gemfile:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/assaf/vanity.git
  revision: d4bdb06b1d6054d3861e1ca93cc0c6e47db3e095
  ref: d4bdb06b1d6054d3861e1ca93cc0c6e47db3e095
  branch: master
  specs:
    vanity (2.0.0.beta8)
      i18n

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/bokmann/business_time.git
  revision: 0782aa46808a412f343e0b851d4a64a3a1aced21
  specs:
    business_time (0.7.4)
      activesupport (>= 3.1.0)
      tzinfo

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/jasonfb/spree.git
  revision: 1038311bf61b2e496547ef502fa4b0e46ac7a44e
  branch: 2-4-stable
  specs:
    spree (2.4.11.beta)
      spree_api (= 2.4.11.beta)
      spree_backend (= 2.4.11.beta)
      spree_cmd (= 2.4.11.beta)
      spree_core (= 2.4.11.beta)
      spree_frontend (= 2.4.11.beta)
      spree_sample (= 2.4.11.beta)
    spree_api (2.4.11.beta)
      rabl (~> 0.9.4.pre1)
      spree_core (= 2.4.11.beta)
      versioncake (~> 2.3.1)
    spree_backend (2.4.11.beta)
      jquery-rails (~> 3.1.2)
      jquery-ui-rails (~> 5.0.0)
      select2-rails (= 3.5.9.1)
      spree_api (= 2.4.11.beta)
      spree_core (= 2.4.11.beta)
    spree_cmd (2.4.11.beta)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    spree_core (2.4.11.beta)
      activemerchant (~> 1.44.1)
      acts_as_list (~> 0.3)
      awesome_nested_set (~> 3.0.1)
      cancancan (~> 1.9.2)
      carmen (~> 1.0.0)
      deface (~> 1.0.0)
      ffaker (~> 1.16)
      font-awesome-rails (~> 4.0)
      friendly_id (~> 5.0.4)
      highline (~> 1.6.18)
      json (~> 1.7)
      kaminari (~> 0.15, >= 0.15.1)
      monetize (~> 1.1)
      paperclip (~> 4.2.0)
      paranoia (~> 2.1.0)
      premailer-rails
      rails (~> 4.1.11)
      ransack (~> 1.4.1)
      state_machine (= 1.2.0)
      stringex (~> 1.5.1)
      truncate_html (= 0.9.2)
      twitter_cldr (~> 3.0)
    spree_frontend (2.4.11.beta)
      canonical-rails (~> 0.0.4)
      jquery-rails (~> 3.1.2)
      spree_api (= 2.4.11.beta)
      spree_core (= 2.4.11.beta)
    spree_sample (2.4.11.beta)
      spree_core (= 2.4.11.beta)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/jasonfb/spree_avatax_certified.git
  revision: c376385f1975e52a3adc38c7088daa4205f36cca
  ref: c376385f1975e52a3adc38c7088daa4205f36cca
  branch: 2-4-stable
  specs:
    spree_avatax_certified (2.4.2)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
      json (~> 1.7)
      logging (~> 1.8)
      psych (~> 2.0.4)
      rest-client (~> 1.7)
      spree_core (~> 2.4.0)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/mackweldon/spree_gateway.git
  revision: 73e3d75452163ef0d6ccb3d1c21951f4ea633ed4
  branch: 2-4-stable
  specs:
    spree_gateway (2.4.0)
      spree_core (~> 2.4.0)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/mackweldon/spree_google_merchant.git
  revision: 6bc864c0d30a30c45900910c2bd3858ff0ee7fd4
  branch: 2-4-stable
  specs:
    spree_google_merchant (2.4.0)
      net-sftp (= 2.1.2)
      spree (~> 2.4)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/mackweldon/spree_shipping_labeler.git
  revision: dc0680a5a63c4400b1265e33082c3f2d42b4fdac
  branch: 2-4-stable
  specs:
    spree_shipping_labeler (2.3.0)
      coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
      fedex (~> 3.6.1)
      spree_core (~> 2.4.0)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/reidcooper/spree_auth_devise.git
  revision: de265a72c568fbeaa09d733351fcd18cb2cad018
  branch: 2-4-stable
  specs:
    spree_auth_devise (2.4.0)
      devise (~> 3.2.3)
      devise-encryptable (= 0.1.2)
      json
      multi_json
      spree_core (~> 2.4.0)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_legacy_return_authorizations.git
  revision: 9968f25e12fd6f19e8fa07fa8e52ece8a1f99475
  branch: master
  specs:
    spree_legacy_return_authorizations (2.4.0)
      spree_core (~> 2.4.0)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_related_products.git
  revision: d3452dbba6a748e75354fd912a893e6669b72063
  branch: 2-4-stable
  specs:
    spree_related_products (3.2)
      spree_backend (~> 2.4.0)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_sitemap.git
  revision: 5ed6b1cb17b32cac9b9eefe4d9d95bad179e211f
  branch: 2-4-stable
  specs:
    spree_sitemap (2.0.0.beta)
      sitemap_generator (~> 4.3.1)
      spree_core (~> 2.4.0)

GIT
  remote: https://github.com/nofxx/symbolize.git
  revision: 58b258c7964ca200c3bdf0061f0c98306bfcbead
  ref: 58b258c7964ca200c3bdf0061f0c98306bfcbead
  specs:
    symbolize (4.5.1)
      activemodel (>= 3.2, < 5)
      activesupport (>= 3.2, < 5)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    CFPropertyList (2.3.0)
    actionmailer (4.1.14.1)
      actionpack (= 4.1.14.1)
      actionview (= 4.1.14.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.1.14.1)
      actionview (= 4.1.14.1)
      activesupport (= 4.1.14.1)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    actionview (4.1.14.1)
      activesupport (= 4.1.14.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
    active_model_serializers (0.9.3)
      activemodel (>= 3.2)
    active_record_query_trace (1.3)
    active_scaffold (3.4.17)
      rails (>= 3.2.18, < 5)
    active_utils (2.2.3)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.11)
      i18n
    activemerchant (1.44.1)
      active_utils (~> 2.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.14, < 5.0.0)
      builder (>= 2.1.2, < 4.0.0)
      i18n (>= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.7)
      nokogiri (~> 1.4)
      offsite_payments (~> 2.0.0)
    activemodel (4.1.14.1)
      activesupport (= 4.1.14.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.1.14.1)
      activemodel (= 4.1.14.1)
      activesupport (= 4.1.14.1)
      arel (~> 5.0.0)
    activerecord-session_store (0.1.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0.0, < 5)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0, < 5)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5)
    activesupport (4.1.14.1)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    acts-as-taggable-on (3.5.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.2, < 5)
    acts_as_list (0.7.2)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
    addressable (2.3.8)
    ancestry (2.1.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)
    arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
    asset_sync (1.1.0)
      activemodel
      fog (>= 1.8.0)
      unf
    audited (4.0.0)
      rails-observers (~> 0.1.2)
    audited-activerecord (4.0.0)
      activerecord (~> 4.0)
      audited (= 4.0.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (5.1.7)
      execjs
      json
    awesome_nested_set (3.0.2)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0, < 5)
    awesome_print (1.6.1)
    aws-sdk (1.27.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
      uuidtools (~> 2.1)
    bcrypt (3.1.10)
    better_errors (2.1.1)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
      rack (>= 0.9.0)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.3)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.0.0.1)
      sass (>= 3.2.19)
    builder (3.2.2)
    bullet (4.14.5)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      uniform_notifier (~> 1.9.0)
    byebug (3.5.1)
      columnize (~> 0.8)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.2)
      slop (~> 3.6)
    callsite (0.0.11)
    camertron-eprun (1.1.0)
    cancancan (1.9.2)
    canonical-rails (0.0.11)
      rails (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
    capybara (2.5.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    capybara-webkit (1.7.1)
      capybara (>= 2.3.0, < 2.6.0)
      json
    carmen (1.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    childprocess (0.5.7)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    ckeditor (4.1.1)
      cocaine
      orm_adapter (~> 0.5.0)
    cldr-plurals-runtime-rb (1.0.1)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.8)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
    colorize (0.7.7)
    columnize (0.9.0)
    commonjs (0.2.7)
    crack (0.4.2)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0.0)
    css_parser (1.3.7)
      addressable
    dalli (2.7.2)
    database_cleaner (1.4.0)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
    deface (1.0.2)
      colorize (>= 0.5.8)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      polyglot
      rails (>= 3.1)
    delayed_paperclip (2.9.1)
      paperclip (>= 3.3)
    devise (3.2.4)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    devise-encryptable (0.1.2)
      devise (>= 2.1.0)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    docile (1.1.5)
    domain_name (0.5.25)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    excon (0.44.1)
    execjs (2.6.0)
    factory_girl (4.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.5.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.5.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    fedex (3.6.1)
      httparty (~> 0.13.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
    ffaker (1.32.1)
    ffi (1.9.10)
    fission (0.5.0)
      CFPropertyList (~> 2.2)
    fog (1.27.0)
      fog-atmos
      fog-aws (~> 0.0)
      fog-brightbox (~> 0.4)
      fog-core (~> 1.27, >= 1.27.3)
      fog-ecloud
      fog-json
      fog-profitbricks
      fog-radosgw (>= 0.0.2)
      fog-sakuracloud (>= 0.0.4)
      fog-serverlove
      fog-softlayer
      fog-storm_on_demand
      fog-terremark
      fog-vmfusion
      fog-voxel
      fog-xml (~> 0.1.1)
      ipaddress (~> 0.5)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.11)
    fog-atmos (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-aws (0.1.0)
      fog-core (~> 1.27)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
      fog-xml (~> 0.1)
      ipaddress (~> 0.8)
    fog-brightbox (0.7.1)
      fog-core (~> 1.22)
      fog-json
      inflecto (~> 0.0.2)
    fog-core (1.28.0)
      builder
      excon (~> 0.38)
      formatador (~> 0.2)
      mime-types
      net-scp (~> 1.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.1.3)
    fog-ecloud (0.0.2)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-json (1.0.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    fog-profitbricks (0.0.1)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
      nokogiri
    fog-radosgw (0.0.3)
      fog-core (>= 1.21.0)
      fog-json
      fog-xml (>= 0.0.1)
    fog-sakuracloud (1.0.0)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-serverlove (0.1.1)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-softlayer (0.4.0)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-storm_on_demand (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-terremark (0.0.3)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-vmfusion (0.0.1)
      fission
      fog-core
    fog-voxel (0.0.2)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-xml (0.1.1)
      fog-core
      nokogiri (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.11)
    font-awesome-rails (4.5.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
    font-awesome-sass (4.3.2.1)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    friendly_id (5.0.5)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)
    haml (4.0.6)
      tilt
    haml_coffee_assets (1.16.0)
      coffee-script (~> 2.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1)
    highline (1.6.21)
    hike (1.2.3)
    hipchat (1.5.2)
      httparty
      mimemagic
    honeybadger (2.0.6)
    htmlentities (4.3.4)
    htmlrender (0.0.0)
    http-cookie (1.0.2)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    httparty (0.13.7)
      json (~> 1.8)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    i18n (0.6.9)
    inflecto (0.0.2)
    ipaddress (0.8.0)
    jasmine-core (2.3.4)
    jasmine-jquery-rails (2.0.3)
    jasmine-rails (0.10.8)
      jasmine-core (>= 1.3, < 3.0)
      phantomjs (>= 1.9)
      railties (>= 3.2.0)
      sprockets-rails
    jquery-fileupload-rails (0.4.4)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      railties (>= 3.1)
      sass (>= 3.2)
    jquery-rails (3.1.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (1.8.3)
    kaminari (0.16.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    kgio (2.9.3)
    launchy (2.4.3)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    less (2.6.0)
      commonjs (~> 0.2.7)
    less-rails (2.6.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      less (~> 2.6.0)
    libv8 (3.16.14.7)
    little-plugger (1.1.4)
    logging (1.8.2)
      little-plugger (>= 1.1.3)
      multi_json (>= 1.8.4)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    marionette-rails (2.4.1)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    meta_request (0.3.4)
      callsite (~> 0.0, >= 0.0.11)
      rack-contrib (~> 1.1)
      railties (>= 3.0.0, < 5.0.0)
    mime-types (2.99)
    mimemagic (0.3.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
    minitest (5.8.4)
    modernizr-rails (2.7.1)
    monetize (1.3.1)
      money (~> 6.6)
    money (6.6.1)
      i18n (>= 0.6.4, <= 0.7.0)
    mono_logger (1.1.0)
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    multi_xml (0.5.5)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    mysql2 (0.3.17)
    net-scp (1.2.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-sftp (2.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (2.9.2)
    netrc (0.11.0)
    newrelic_rpm (3.9.9.275)
    nokogiri (1.6.7)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.0.0.rc2)
    nondestructive_migrations (1.1)
      activerecord (>= 4.0)
    offsite_payments (2.0.1)
      active_utils (~> 2.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.14, < 5.0.0)
      builder (>= 2.1.2, < 4.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
      json (~> 1.7)
      money (< 7.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.4)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pagerduty (2.0.0)
      json (>= 1.7.7)
    paperclip (4.2.4)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.5)
      mime-types
    paranoia (2.1.4)
      activerecord (~> 4.0)
    pdf-core (0.4.0)
    phantomjs (1.9.8.0)
    polyamorous (1.2.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
    polyglot (0.3.5)
    prawn (1.3.0)
      pdf-core (~> 0.4.0)
      ttfunk (~> 1.4.0)
    premailer (1.8.6)
      css_parser (>= 1.3.6)
      htmlentities (>= 4.0.0)
    premailer-rails (1.8.2)
      actionmailer (>= 3, < 5)
      premailer (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.9)
    psych (2.0.15)
    quiet_assets (1.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
    rabl (0.9.4.pre1)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.14)
    rack (1.5.5)
    rack-attack (4.3.0)
      rack
    rack-contrib (1.2.0)
      rack (>= 0.9.1)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rack-timeout (0.2.0)
    rack_session_access (0.1.1)
      builder (>= 2.0.0)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rails (4.1.14.1)
      actionmailer (= 4.1.14.1)
      actionpack (= 4.1.14.1)
      actionview (= 4.1.14.1)
      activemodel (= 4.1.14.1)
      activerecord (= 4.1.14.1)
      activesupport (= 4.1.14.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.1.14.1)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    rails-observers (0.1.2)
      activemodel (~> 4.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.4)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.1.14.1)
      actionpack (= 4.1.14.1)
      activesupport (= 4.1.14.1)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    raindrops (0.13.0)
    rake (10.5.0)
    ransack (1.4.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      i18n
      polyamorous (~> 1.1)
    redis (3.2.0)
    redis-namespace (1.5.1)
      redis (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.4)
    ref (1.0.5)
    resque (1.25.2)
      mono_logger (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      redis-namespace (~> 1.3)
      sinatra (>= 0.9.2)
      vegas (~> 0.1.2)
    resque-cleaner (0.3.0)
      resque (~> 1.0)
    resque-loner (1.3.0)
      resque (~> 1.0)
    resque-retry (1.4.0)
      resque (~> 1.25)
      resque-scheduler (~> 4.0)
    resque-scheduler (4.0.0)
      mono_logger (~> 1.0)
      redis (~> 3.0)
      resque (~> 1.25)
      rufus-scheduler (~> 3.0)
    resque_mailer (2.2.7)
      actionmailer (>= 3.0)
    resque_spec (0.15.0)
      resque (>= 1.19.0)
      rspec-core (>= 2.5.0)
      rspec-expectations (>= 2.5.0)
      rspec-mocks (>= 2.5.0)
    rest-client (1.8.0)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3.0)
      netrc (~> 0.7)
    rspec (3.3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.3.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.3.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.3.0)
    rspec-core (3.3.2)
      rspec-support (~> 3.3.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.3.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.3.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.3.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.3.0)
    rspec-rails (3.3.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      rspec-core (~> 3.3.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.3.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.3.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.3.0)
    rspec-support (3.3.0)
    rubyzip (1.1.7)
    rufus-scheduler (3.0.9)
      tzinfo
    safe_yaml (1.0.4)
    sailthru-client (4.0.1)
      json
      multipart-post
    sass (3.4.13)
    sass-rails (5.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1)
    select2-rails (3.5.9.1)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    selenium-webdriver (2.48.1)
      childprocess (~> 0.5)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip (~> 1.0)
      websocket (~> 1.0)
    settingslogic (2.0.9)
    shoulda-matchers (2.8.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    simplecov (0.9.1)
      docile (~> 1.1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.8.0)
    simplecov-html (0.8.0)
    sinatra (1.4.5)
      rack (~> 1.4)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.4)
    sitemap_generator (4.3.1)
      builder
    slim (3.0.2)
      temple (~> 0.7.3)
      tilt (>= 1.3.3, < 2.1)
    slop (3.6.0)
    sprockets (2.12.4)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.3.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    state_machine (1.2.0)
    stringex (1.5.1)
    temple (0.7.5)
    therubyracer (0.12.1)
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
      ref
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    truncate_html (0.9.2)
    ttfunk (1.4.0)
    twitter-bootstrap-rails (3.2.0)
      actionpack (~> 4.1)
      execjs (~> 2.2)
      rails (~> 4.1)
      railties (~> 4.1)
    twitter_cldr (3.2.1)
      camertron-eprun
      cldr-plurals-runtime-rb (~> 1.0.0)
      json
      tzinfo
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.7.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.7.1)
    unicorn (4.8.3)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      rack
      raindrops (~> 0.7)
    uniform_notifier (1.9.0)
    uuidtools (2.1.5)
    vcr (2.9.3)
    vegas (0.1.11)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    versioncake (2.3.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.2)
      railties (>= 3.2)
      tzinfo
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    webmock (1.20.4)
      addressable (>= 2.3.6)
      crack (>= 0.3.2)
    websocket (1.2.2)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  active_model_serializers
  active_record_query_trace
  active_scaffold (= 3.4.17)
  activerecord-session_store
  acts-as-taggable-on (~> 3.4)
  acts_as_list
  ancestry
  asset_sync
  audited-activerecord (~> 4.0)
  awesome_print
  aws-sdk (= 1.27.0)
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller
  bootstrap-sass (~> 3.3.3)
  bullet
  business_time!
  byebug
  capybara (= 2.5.0)
  capybara-webkit
  ckeditor
  coffee-rails
  dalli
  database_cleaner
  delayed_paperclip
  execjs
  factory_girl_rails
  ffaker
  fog (~> 1.20)
  font-awesome-sass
  haml
  haml_coffee_assets
  hipchat
  honeybadger (= 2.0.6)
  htmlrender
  i18n (= 0.6.9)
  jasmine-jquery-rails
  jasmine-rails
  jquery-fileupload-rails
  jquery-rails (~> 3.1.3)
  launchy
  less-rails
  libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
  marionette-rails
  meta_request
  modernizr-rails
  mysql2 (= 0.3.17)
  newrelic_rpm
  nondestructive_migrations (= 1.1)
  pagerduty
  paperclip
  prawn
  quiet_assets
  rack-attack
  rack-timeout
  rack_session_access
  rails (= 4.1.14.1)
  rails_12factor
  redis
  resque
  resque-cleaner
  resque-loner
  resque-retry
  resque-scheduler
  resque_mailer
  resque_spec
  rspec
  rspec-mocks
  rspec-rails
  rubyzip (>= 1.0.0)
  sailthru-client
  sass-rails
  selenium-webdriver (= 2.48.1)
  settingslogic
  shoulda-matchers
  simplecov
  slim
  spree!
  spree_auth_devise!
  spree_avatax_certified!
  spree_gateway!
  spree_google_merchant!
  spree_legacy_return_authorizations!
  spree_related_products!
  spree_shipping_labeler!
  spree_sitemap!
  symbolize!
  therubyracer
  twitter-bootstrap-rails (= 3.2.0)
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  unicorn
  vanity!
  vcr
  webmock

BUNDLED WITH
   1.10.6
```

Error Log:

```
Started GET "/spec/javascripts/fixtures/savings_meter" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-25 19:13:22 -0500
Processing by JasmineFixturesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"savings_meter"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 74ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (5 for 4):
  actionview (4.1.14.1) lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:121:in `block in find_all_anywhere'
  actionview (4.1.14.1) lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:151:in `block in cached'
  actionview (4.1.14.1) lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:62:in `cache'
  actionview (4.1.14.1) lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:150:in `cached'
  actionview (4.1.14.1) lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:120:in `find_all_anywhere'
  actionview (4.1.14.1) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in _find_all'
  actionview (4.1.14.1) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:66:in `block in _find_all'
  actionview (4.1.14.1) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:65:in `_find_all'
  actionview (4.1.14.1) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:50:in `find_file'
  actionview (4.1.14.1) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:129:in `find_file'
  actionview (4.1.14.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:18:in `find_file'
  actionview (4.1.14.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:33:in `block in determine_template'
  actionview (4.1.14.1) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:149:in `with_fallbacks'
  actionview (4.1.14.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:18:in `with_fallbacks'
  actionview (4.1.14.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:33:in `determine_template'
  actionview (4.1.14.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:8:in `render'
  actionview (4.1.14.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.1.14.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (4.1.14.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.1.14.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.1.14.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.1.14.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.1.14.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.1.14.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.1.14.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.1.14.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.1.14.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /Users/reidcooper/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.1.14.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.1.14.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.1.14.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.1.14.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.1.14.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
  active_scaffold (3.4.17) lib/active_scaffold/extensions/action_controller_rendering.rb:14:in `render_with_active_scaffold'
  app/controllers/jasmine_fixtures_controller.rb:4:in `show'
```

Comment: You might want to include the full error message.

Comment: I just added the error log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a bug in ActionView.

The method is defined with [four parameters](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6dfab475ca230dfcad7a603483431c8e7a8f908e/actionview/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb#L146), but called with [five](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6dfab475ca230dfcad7a603483431c8e7a8f908e/actionview/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb#L131).

EDIT: Actually [a known and closed issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23243).

Answer (score 1):

A security related fix in rails clashes with rspec-rails (see [issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1532)) and affects uses of `render file:'...'`

rspec-rails 3.4.1 fixes this issue.